# How to resize window in sfml?

Tags: c++, resize, sfml

I don't know how to resize a window in sfml while my application is open. I tried to use pointers, but it did not work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: *but it did not worked.* A) show us what you tried B) clearly define "did not work"

Comment: Have you tried RenderWindow.setSize(x,y)? That's how the SFML documentation recommends resizing the window.

Comment: thanks Roboinventor! It's window.setSize(Vector2u(x,y));

Comment: So did that solve your problem?

Comment: @Roboinventor if you had posted the comment as answer, he could now simply accept it as such. You know that's how SO is supposed to work. :D

Comment: @Lukas yeah, when I first posted that I wasn't sure if he had tried it or not so I wanted to confirm that before making the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using window.setSize(Vector2u(x,y)) as shown in the [SFML documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.3.1/classsf_1_1RenderWindow.php)